# Constructing a formula in first order logic

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, first-order-logic

Let $\tau = \{+, ·, 0, 1\}$ be a signature with the binary function symbols $+$ and $\cdot$ and the constant symbols $0$ and $1$. We deﬁne the $\tau$-structure $\mathbb{R} = (R, +^R, \cdot^R, 0^R, 1^R),$ so that $+^R$ is the usual addition and $\cdot^R$ is the usual multiplication on the real numbers and $0^R = 0$ and $1^R = 1.$ Furthermore, let $\rho: = \{ +, 0\} \subseteq\tau$ and $S$ the $\rho$-reduct of $R.$

Construct a formula $\varphi (x, y) \in FO [\tau]$ such that $\varphi(R) = \{(a, b) | a, b \in R\ and \ a <b\}$. Show that there is no formula $\psi (x, y) \in FO [\rho]$ such that $\psi (S) = \{(a, b) | a, b \in R\ and\ a <b\}.$

I have no idea where to start with this task. Can someone, please, help me?

Comment: To construct the $\varphi$, you'll have to express in terms of the $\tau$-structure the property that $x<y$. Do you have an idea how to start with that?

Comment: And in order the show that no such $\psi$ exists, you could try to show that if some pair $(x,y)$ satisfies $\psi$, then also $(-x,-y)$ will

Comment: @hgmath No, I don't. Can you, please, show me, or give me another hint for both?

Comment: Hint: $x<y$ if and only if $x+z=y$ for some positive number $z$

Comment: So can we write $\varphi=(\forall x,y\in R)(\exists z\in R^+)(x+z=y)$ or I can't use $R^+?$ @hgmath

Comment: no you can't use $R^+$, try to express it using the symbols in $\tau$

Comment: @hgmath And how to write z then?

Comment: @math_ "nonnegativeness" can be expressed using $\tau$ (hint: multiplication is needed)

Comment: is that also you, @math_algebra?